# Cannot Bind List View Drop Down

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, drop-down-menu

How do I bind a dropdown in a Listview to the database *and* the dropdown list.

E.g. Drop down has two choices Left and Right. The dropdown writes back to the database. Issue is that I have records in the database that *already* have 'Left' or 'Right' recorded for that data item.

I don't know how to include the evaluated or bound item in the drop down list. Does this make sense to anyone!!!??????

```
                <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddLeftOrRight" DataTextField=<%# Bind("LeftOrRight") %> runat ="server" >
                <asp:ListItem Value= ""></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="L"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="R"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList></td>
```

Comment: Why do you bind to DataTextField - DataTextField=<%# Bind("LeftOrRight") %> and then again provide ListItem values manually?

Comment: It's messy! The web form captures data. But sometimes the user has already opened it and saved part of the form already. So if they have I want that field to display the information previously entered rather than show the drop down list.